# Classifying the real irreducible representations of a compact torus

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $T:=(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})^r$ denote the rank $r$ compact torus.
We know that all of its irreducible complex representations are one-dimensional given by the characters $$\chi_{k_1,\dots,k_r}(x_1,\dots,x_r):=\exp\left(2\pi i \sum_{i=1}^r k_ix_i\right)$$ for $k_1,\dots,k_r\in \mathbb{Z}$.

**Goal:**
I would like to prove that any irreducible real representations of $T$ is either the trivial representation (corresponding to $k_i=0,\forall i$) or a two-dimensional representation, for $k_1,\dots,k_r\in \mathbb{Z}$ not all zero, given by
$$
(x_1,\dots,x_r) \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} \cos(2\pi \sum_{i=1}^r k_ix_i) & \sin(2\pi \sum_{i=1}^r k_ix_i) \\ -\sin(2\pi \sum_{i=1}^r k_ix_i) & \cos(2\pi \sum_{i=1}^r k_ix_i)\end{pmatrix}
$$
and let's denote it by $W_{k_1,\dots,k_r}$.

My **attempt** is that, given any nontrivial irreducible real representation $(\pi,V)$ of $T$, we can take its complexification $V\otimes \mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{C}^{\dim_{\mathbb{R}}(V)}$ which is then a direct sum of complex characters $\chi_{k_1,\dots,k_r}$ with $k_1,\dots,k_r$ not all zero.
Since $V$ is real, these nontrivial characters come up in conjugate pairs.
Since
$$
\begin{pmatrix} \cos(2\pi \sum_{i=1}^r k_ix_i) & \sin(2\pi \sum_{i=1}^r k_ix_i) \\ -\sin(2\pi \sum_{i=1}^r k_ix_i) & \cos(2\pi \sum_{i=1}^r k_ix_i)\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ i & -i \end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ i & -i \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} \exp(2\pi i \sum_{i=1}^r k_ix_i) & 0 \\ 0 & \exp(-2\pi i \sum_{i=1}^r k_ix_i)\end{pmatrix}
$$
we see that $\chi_{k_1,\dots,k_r}\oplus \chi_{-k_1,\dots,-k_r} \cong_{\mathbb{C}} W_{k_1,\dots,k_r}\otimes \mathbb{C}$.
So I wonder, does this show that $V\cong_{\mathbb{R}} W_{k_1,\dots,k_r}$ as real representations?

**Question:**
Could anybody salvage the above argument, or give a new argument, to prove the classification of irreducible real representations of the compact torus $T$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I should mention that, I came across this result as Proposition 15.5 in Daniel Bump's "Lie Groups", second edition, where Bump asserts that this follows from the classification of complex irreducible representations, without giving further justifications.